# MySQL - nested inner joins make the query vey slow - solutions?

Tags: sql, mysql, hibernate

I have a query:

```
select count(*) from transaction_entry 
inner join inventory_item on inventory_item_id = inventory_item.id
inner join transaction on transaction_id = transaction.id
inner join product on inventory_item.product_id = product.id
```

when adding the last inner join, so to `product` table, the query becomes very slow - from 5s, to 40s, are there any ways to improve the performance of this nested join?
I have indexes for ids in those tables, so the solution should aim for something else than indexes.

Edit:
If I use those queries separetely, they seem to be very fast, the problem occurs when I try to join `transaction` table and `inventory_item` table together:

```sql
select count(*) from transaction_entry 
inner join inventory_item on inventory_item_id = inventory_item.id
inner join product on inventory_item.product_id = product.id
```

the above is very fast

```sql
select count(*) from transaction_entry 
inner join transaction on transaction_id = transaction.id
inner join inventory_item on inventory_item_id = inventory_item.id
```

the above is very slow

```sql
select count(*) from transaction_entry 
inner join transaction on transaction_id = transaction.id
```

the above again is very fast

The explain of the query:

```sql
select count(*) from transaction_entry 
inner join inventory_item on inventory_item_id = inventory_item.id
inner join transaction on transaction_id = transaction.id
inner join product on inventory_item.product_id = product.id
```

[image]

`innodb_buffer_pool_size: 134217728`

`transaction_entry` table is 994MB

`transaction` table is 504MB

`inventory_item` table is 23MB

`product` table is 24MB

[image]

and whole explain:

```
id|select_type|table            |partitions|type  |possible_keys                        |key               |key_len|ref                                    |rows |filtered|Extra                   |
--+-----------+-----------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------+------------------+-------+---------------------------------------+-----+--------+------------------------+
 1|SIMPLE     |inventory_item   |          |index |PRIMARY,product_id                   |product_id        |883    |                                       |73470|   100.0|Using where; Using index|
 1|SIMPLE     |product          |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY,idx_product_id               |PRIMARY           |114    |dbdev3.inventory_item.product_id       |    1|   100.0|Using index             |
 1|SIMPLE     |transaction_entry|          |ref   |FKABC21FD1AA992CED,FKABC21FD12EF4C7F4|FKABC21FD1AA992CED|115    |dbdev3.inventory_item.id               |   21|   100.0|Using where             |
 1|SIMPLE     |transaction      |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY                              |PRIMARY           |114    |dbdev3.transaction_entry.transaction_id|    1|   100.0|Using index             |  |
```

`transaction_entry` create table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `transaction_entry` (
  `id` char(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `version` bigint NOT NULL,
  `inventory_item_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int NOT NULL,
  `transaction_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_entries_idx` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `bin_location_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKABC21FD1AA992CED` (`inventory_item_id`),
  KEY `FKABC21FD12EF4C7F4` (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `FKABC21FD169DB749D` (`bin_location_id`),
  KEY `FKABC21FD1DED5FAE7` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKABC21FD12EF4C7F4` FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_id`) REFERENCES `transaction` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKABC21FD169DB749D` FOREIGN KEY (`bin_location_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKABC21FD1AA992CED` FOREIGN KEY (`inventory_item_id`) REFERENCES `inventory_item` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKABC21FD1DED5FAE7` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

`transaction` table create table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` char(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `version` bigint NOT NULL,
  `created_by_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `destination_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inventory_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `source_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `transaction_type_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmed` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmed_by_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_confirmed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incoming_shipment_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outgoing_shipment_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requisition_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receipt_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DE3265A8A9` (`confirmed_by_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DE217F5972` (`created_by_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DE1E2B3CDC` (`destination_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DE72A2C5B4` (`inventory_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DE828481AF` (`source_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DEB3FB7111` (`transaction_type_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DE426DD105` (`updated_by_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DE5DE9E374` (`requisition_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DE5F12AFED` (`incoming_shipment_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DEB80B3233` (`outgoing_shipment_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DED08EDBE6` (`order_id`),
  KEY `FK7FA0D2DEF7076438` (`receipt_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE1E2B3CDC` FOREIGN KEY (`destination_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE217F5972` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE3265A8A9` FOREIGN KEY (`confirmed_by_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE426DD105` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE5DE9E374` FOREIGN KEY (`requisition_id`) REFERENCES `requisition` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE5F12AFED` FOREIGN KEY (`incoming_shipment_id`) REFERENCES `shipment` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE72A2C5B4` FOREIGN KEY (`inventory_id`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE828481AF` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DEB3FB7111` FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_type_id`) REFERENCES `transaction_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DEB80B3233` FOREIGN KEY (`outgoing_shipment_id`) REFERENCES `shipment` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DED08EDBE6` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `order` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DEF7076438` FOREIGN KEY (`receipt_id`) REFERENCES `receipt` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

`inventory_item` create table table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `inventory_item` (
  `id` char(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `version` bigint NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lot_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiration_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_id` (`product_id`,`lot_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKFE019416DED5FAE7` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

`product` create table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` char(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `version` bigint NOT NULL,
  `category_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_of_measure_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cold_chain` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ndc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_of_measure` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_uom_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `package_size` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `controlled_substance` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `essential` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hazardous_material` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot_control` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serialized` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_per_unit` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reconditioned` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_type_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `abc_class` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost_per_unit` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gl_account_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot_and_expiry_control` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_family_id` char(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`product_code`),
  KEY `FKED8DCCEFEF4C770D` (`category_id`),
  KEY `FKED8DCCEF217F5972` (`created_by_id`),
  KEY `FKED8DCCEFEEB2908D` (`default_uom_id`),
  KEY `FKED8DCCEF426DD105` (`updated_by_id`),
  KEY `FKED8DCCEFABD88AC6` (`product_type_id`),
  KEY `fk_product_gl_account` (`gl_account_id`),
  KEY `fk_product_product_family` (`product_family_id`),
  KEY `idx_product_id` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_gl_account` FOREIGN KEY (`gl_account_id`) REFERENCES `gl_account` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_product_family` FOREIGN KEY (`product_family_id`) REFERENCES `product_group` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKED8DCCEF217F5972` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKED8DCCEF426DD105` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKED8DCCEFABD88AC6` FOREIGN KEY (`product_type_id`) REFERENCES `product_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKED8DCCEFEEB2908D` FOREIGN KEY (`default_uom_id`) REFERENCES `unit_of_measure` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKED8DCCEFEF4C770D` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  What is the final `COUNT`?  How big are the tables?  And, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames I've updated the question with EXPLAIN SELECT attached.
The final count is 1 million, but it should not matter, because it was even slow when the results were around 30000 (after adding a proper WHERE)

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (each_table-of-your-three-tables) so we can see what the optimizer is dealing with at SELECT / JOIN of tables.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added it to the post, thanks in advance for help

Comment: Could someone explain how is it possible that when joining only product and inventory item, the EXPLAIN result of rows seems to be 17000 for product and 4 for inventory_item whereas after adding join to the transaction table, the inventory_item rows EXPLAIN result becomes 75000? 
Is this the reason why the performance is so poor? Can we improve it somehow?

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but it seems that when joining inventory_item, it never uses the PRIMARY key, it always uses the `product_id`, and always scans all rows in `inventory_item` table. Is it expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it was slow, it was probably very I/O-bound.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size: 134217728
```

is an old default.  Raise it to about 70% of available RAM so that more data can be cached in RAM.

Also...

- `char(38)` -- smells like some sort of UUID.  This can add to the disk space and sluggishness.  (However, increasing the buffer_pool setting will probably mask these issues until the data gets much bigger.)  See also:  [*UUIDs*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid)
- NULLable columns in `UNIQUE` keys seems 'wrong'.
- As for "I don't know if this matters,... it never uses the PRIMARY key, ..." , note that

  ```
    UNIQUE KEY `product_id` (`product_id`,`lot_number`)
  ```

  is a BTree that implicitly contains contains `id`.  Hence the query that needs only `id` and `product_id` is actually wise to use this structure instead of the larger BTree that contains all the columns of the table.

Comment: thanks, I will try and get back there. Anyway, a question - if it "always uses" the index of `product_id` and `lot_number`, why do you say it contains `id`? I thought it contains only `product_id`, `lot_number` and eventually a pointer to the disk location of a particular row. Am I wrong?

Comment: thank you, after bumping up the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` it went down from 40 seconds to around 3 seconds. I've bumped it up only from the default 128MB to 1GB and the difference is huge.
Anyway, is there anything from the "query perspective" except what you wrote, that you think could help?
And answering the uuid stuff - yes, it's UUID that are the ids. I'm not the owner of the project, so I wasn't a part of doing it as `char(38)`.

Comment: but after running the proper query, so not `count(*)` but selecting actual data, it is still very slow (nothing really changed before/after the bumping up...), any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that it is that slow because of the Hibernate that then maps the results into a domain?

Comment: What helped a bit was bumping up the heap space for JVM.

Comment: @sunny - Secondary indexes find the data via the Primary Key, which it tacked onto the columns of the secondary index.  So, assuming `PRIMARY KEY(id)`,  `INDEX(a,b)` is an ordered list of the triple `(a,b,id)`.  (The `id` serves as the "record pointer" that is used in some other RDBMS's`)

Comment: @sunny - UUIDs are very random.  Random tends to quickly invalidate what is in the cache.  Conclusion: those lookups in the other tables are leading to churn in the buffer_pool.  (Of course, replacing UUIDs with AUTO_INCREMENTs would be a major chore.)  You have not said how much RAM you have, nor how big the JVM heap is.  Adding memory is a second-best solution.

Comment: @sunny - and...   There are a hundred frameworks (eg, Hibernate); I make no attempt to understand each and every one.  I can't even keep track of what inefficiencies each one dumps onto the database.  What I sarcastically say is that frameworks are good for toy implementations, but fall flat when used for serious applications, especially when the data grows beyond "small".  Your app seems to be in this case.  If Hibernate encourages those UUIDs, then I blame it.  (UUIDs do have a use, but should not be the default.)

Answer (score 0):

1. first you need to add index in tables

```
CREATE INDEX idx_inventory_item_id ON transaction_entry (inventory_item_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_transaction_id ON transaction_entry (transaction_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_product_id ON inventory_item (product_id);ry
```

2. Try this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_entries
FROM transaction_entry TE
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM inventory_item II
   INNER JOIN transaction T ON TE.transaction_id = T.id
   INNER JOIN product P ON II.product_id = P.id
   WHERE TE.inventory_item_id = II.id
);
```

Comment: Copied from chat gpt..... 1. I said I have indexes, 2. this query takes the same amount of time

Comment: Assumin that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table, none of these indexes are needed for the query in question.

Comment: @RickJames what do you mean? So should I add any? I've added the ones Mohammed mentioned, but they didn't help at all

Comment: @sunny - I mean that Mohammed's indexes won't be used, hence won't "help at all", as you found out.

Comment: (Who is saying what came from chat gpt?)  Mohammed wrote this Answer _before_ Sunny provided the indexes.  Please realize that AI is barely "Alpha" quality; anything from it should be seriously scrutinized.

Answer (score -1):

Sunny, Consider CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i_i_idx_unq_product_id ON inventory_item (product_id); to minimize the key_len used (883) to join to product table. New EXPLAIN should be using KEY_LEN of 114 and reduced ROWS count below 73,470 - to save time.
View profile, please.

Comment: What suggests that `product_id` _by itself_ can be `UNIQUE`?

Comment: `product_id` by itself is not unique. It's `product_id` + `lot_number` pair that is unique.

Comment: You are both so correct.  My Apologies.  

This URL may have clue for your possible solution,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73236493/left-join-with-select-distinct-in-table-2  - not tested by me.  Read the whole question and answers, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Please do not reference SQL Server optimization Questions when addressing MySQL Questions.  There are too many differences in their Optimizers.  Suggest deleting this Answer.

Comment: @RickJames Could it be that in this case, MySQL offers JOIN xxxx DISTINCT to achieve Sunny's objective?  Different specifically for MS Sql but with the same goal of reducing rows examined that is good for everyone.

Comment: No, MySQL does not have `JOIN...DISTINCT`.